# How to find out a future entry salary when interviewing for a bachelor thesis?

Tags: salary, germany

I am currently looking for a company where I will be writing my bachelor thesis next year. Since computer scientists are in very high demand, I am almost certain that the company I chose, will offer me a job afterwards and I also plan on doing that. This is why I am making an extra effort to select a good company that I will want to stay and work for, for at least a few years.

Obviously one important point is the salary. Since I am only interviewing for a bachelor thesis I can't really negotiate the future salary.

**In my situation what is a good way to find out what a prospective company would pay as an entry salary?**

I understand that it will depend on my qualification when I start but I suppose that the range differs from company to company. Can I just ask the interviewer or would that be rude? I don't want to come across as someone who is only interested in money but not the subject/company itself. Please give some examples on how to formulate the question.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of the proposed question, because I am not in an job interview setting, but looking for a company to do my bachelor thesis. This is a different situation. Only if an answer can show that everything is exactly the same the conclusion would be that it is a duplicate.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? I am not asking how to find out what to ask for but what a specific company usually pays? Did you even read my question?

Comment: In Germany you could check, if the company is 'tarifgebunden'. That means salaries are negotiated and agreed with big unions (e.g. 'IG Metall'). Those base salary tables can be googled. Usually large traditional companies are 'tarifgebunden'. Be aware 'Haustarifvertrag' usually means the salaries are not negotiated with the big unions and are maybe lower.

Answer (score 2):

Society has drilled into us this notion that when interviewing for jobs, companies/hiring managers are in a position of power and therefore candidates should fear saying the wrong thing or asking the wrong question.

I argue anyone hiring has a need for someone with specific skills. As a qualified candidate, you need to establish yourself as an equal in the interview and ask any and all questions which would impact your decision to work there. Compensation is a big one.

To answer your question directly, ask them what their salaries are when the time is right. Before doing so, do research about this company and others on glassdoor, research about your position using salary.com, and determine what salary you want and you believe you're worth.

I'd say the majority of entry level positions have salary bands set in stone, so they will likely tell you what it is. But be prepared to answer when they ask you what you're looking for and give reasons why.

Interview them even more than they interview you.

Comment: I like this question but *when the time is right* is the major part of my question. Can you be more specific on what the right time is?

Comment: @problemofficer during the interview process is when the time is right. There needs to be empathy on both sides of the interviewing table. Anyone looking to hire you should expect that compensation will factor in to whether or not you accept their position. 

If they don't bring up compensation for the role, you must. Be prepared for a range they are likely to provide, and to have reasons why you deserve the number you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is your situation is largely what it is in general: look at sites like Glassdoor, see if you can find people who work there who are willing to talk about their salary, find job postings from the company. As for asking the interview, emphasize your interest in staying with the company. Say something like "I'd be interested in staying on with this company when this is finished. What sort of opportunities would there be?" It shows interest in the company, and is asking about more than just money.